# Dataset transformation

Tags: r, spss

I have a SPSS dataset with 3 columns ("companies", "date", "return") like this:

[Initial Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCpho.png)

Now I would like to transform it so that only dates show up in a row and each company return for a given date is in a separate column, like this:

[Final Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3j4A.png)

Is there an easy way to do that in either SPSS or R?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please avoid posting pictures of data. Use `dput` instead to make reproducible example(s). [Give this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) a read. Thanks

Comment: You could use `dcast` from `reshape2`

Comment: i.e. `dcast(df1, date~companies, value.var= "return")`

Answer (score 0):

In SPSS:

```
sort cases by date companies.
casestovars /id=date /index=companies /separator="_".
```